# Noise covariance matrix

Tags: noise, matched-filter, covariance

I am attempting to implement a generalized least squares estimator that uses a noise covariance matrix from measured data. The basic model is as follows

$$\hat{c}_{GLS} = \left(\bf{A}^T\bf{\Sigma}^{-1}\bf{A}\right)^{-1}\bf{A}^T\bf{\Sigma}^{-1}\bf{r}$$

where $\bf{A}$ is a matrix of my basis functions, $\bf{\Sigma}$ is the noise covariance matrix and $\bf{r}=[r_x r_y r_z]^T$ is a column vector of my vector measurements ordered as shown. Likewise the noise vector measurements are $\bf{n}=[n_x n_y n_z]^T$.

The statement is made in the paper that $\Sigma = E\left\{\bf{n}\bf{n}^T\right\}$, which results in $\Sigma$ being size $3N\times 3N$ which makes sense. However, when I do this I get horrible results and the structure of $\Sigma$ doesn't look right. I expect it to be diagonal dominant and then falling off.

- My question is what am I doing wrong?
- How do I build the noise covariance matrix correctly?

I have data for $\bf{n}=[n_x n_y n_z]^T$
 It isn't just the $3\times 3$ covariance matrix I am use to dealing with.

Edit: added code

`minutes = 5;
NSamples    = Fs*60*minutes;
NOverlap    = NSamples/2;
Sigma = zeros(3*NSamples,3*NSamples);
M=20;`

`for nn = 1:M`

```
nStart = (nn-1)*NOverlap+1;
nStop  = nStart+NSamples-1;
nx = x1(nStart:nStop);
ny = y1(nStart:nStop);
nz = z1(nStart:nStop);
Rxx = xcov(nx );Rxx= (Rxx(NSamples:end));
Rxy = xcov(nx,ny );Rxy= (Rxy(NSamples:end));
Rxz = xcov(nx,nz );Rxz= (Rxz(NSamples:end));
Ryy = xcov(ny );Ryy= (Ryy(NSamples:end));
Rzz = xcov(nz );Rzz= (Rzz(NSamples:end));
Ryz = xcov(ny, nz );Ryz= (Ryz(NSamples:end));

N   = [toeplitz(Rxx) toeplitz(Rxy) toeplitz(Rxz);
       toeplitz(Rxy) toeplitz(Ryy) toeplitz(Ryz);
       toeplitz(Rxz) toeplitz(Ryz) toeplitz(Rzz)];
Sigma = N + Sigma;
```

`end
Sigma = Sigma/M;`

Comment: Maybe you did not implement the expectation operator. I mean it is correct that $\Sigma$ shoud be diagonal-dominant. And $\Sigma = E\{\bf{n}\bf{n}^T\}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i \{\bf{n_i}\bf{n_i}^T\}$ where $\bf{n_i}$ is one realization of noise and $N$ is the number of realizations.

Comment: @AlexTP I did exactly what you describe and the matrix I get back is pure garbage, not diagonal dominant at all, not banded structure like I expect.

Comment: Post your code and part of your result and we will see.

Comment: @AlexTP I added my MATLAB code. Sorry the delay, I was on travel.

Comment: I dont know how your noise `x1,y1,z1` were generated or were processed, but to have your expected result, i.e. diagonal dominant matrix, the elements of x1, y1,z1 must be uncorrelated. Below is the extra code I added

       `NN = M * NOverlap * 2;
       x1 = randn(1,NN) + 1i * randn(1,NN);
       y1 = randn(1,NN) + 1i * randn(1,NN);
       z1 = randn(1,NN) + 1i * randn(1,NN);`

Comment: And the diagonal dominant result,

    `abs(Sigma(1:5,1:5))
    ans =
    
       124.4186     1.0507     6.5347     7.1410     2.6753
         1.0507   124.4186     1.0507     6.5347     7.1410
         6.5347     1.0507   124.4186     1.0507     6.5347
         7.1410     6.5347     1.0507   124.4186     1.0507
         2.6753     7.1410     6.5347     1.0507   124.4186`

Comment: @AlexTP my x1,y1,z1 are from data, they aren't artificially generated.

Comment: Thus they are probably not uncorrelated as you thought, in this case do not expect diagonal dominant covariance matrix. A keyword could be "whitenning filter"

Comment: @AlexTP Yes, that's another method I'm considering implemented through a linear predictor.